# Graph implementation using FIFO lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, graph, homework

I've made a little implementation of an undirected graph, using FIFO lists, for one of my homeworks. Never really knew how to write a proper FIFO data structure, so I would be glad to see some opinion of yours.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    class Node
    {
        struct adj
        {
            int data;
            adj* next;
        };

        adj* head;
        adj* tail;
        int num;
    public:
        Node();
        Node(const Node&);
        Node& operator=(const Node&);
        bool is_empty();
        bool is_leaf();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        void print();
        ~Node();
    };

    int num_nodes;
    Node* nodes;
public:
    Graph(int);
    Graph(ifstream&);
    Graph(const Graph&);
    void add_edge(int, int);
    Node& operator[](int);
    void print();
    ~Graph();
};

Graph::Node::Node()
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    num=0;
}

Graph::Node::Node(const Node& F)
{
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;
    num=0;

    adj* tmp=F.head;

    while(tmp)
    {
        push(tmp->data);
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}

Graph::Node& Graph::Node::operator=(const Node& F)
{
    if(this!=&F)
    {
        head=NULL;
        tail=NULL;
        num=0;

        adj* tmp=F.head;

        while(tmp)
        {
            push(tmp->data);
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

bool Graph::Node::is_empty()
{
    return head==NULL;
}

bool Graph::Node::is_leaf()
{
    return num==1;
}

void Graph::Node::push(int value)
{
    adj* tmp=new adj;

    tmp->data=value;
    tmp->next=NULL;

    if(is_empty())
    {
        head=tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next=tmp;
    }

    tail=tmp;

    num++;
}

int Graph::Node::pop()
{
    if(!is_empty())
    {
        adj* tmp=head;

        head=head->next;

        int value=tmp->data;

        delete tmp;

        num--;

        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

void Graph::Node::print()
{
    adj*tmp=head;

    while(tmp)
    {
        cout<<tmp->data<<" ";
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

Graph::Node::~Node()
{
    while(!is_empty())
    {
        pop();
    }
}

Graph::Graph(int num_nodes)
{
    this->num_nodes=num_nodes;
    nodes=new Node[num_nodes+1];
}

Graph::Graph(ifstream& f)
{
    f>>num_nodes;

    nodes=new Node[num_nodes+1];

    int start, end;

    while(f>>start>>end)
    {
        add_edge(start, end);
    }
}

Graph::Graph(const Graph& G)
{
    num_nodes=G.num_nodes;

    nodes=new Node[num_nodes+1];

    for(int i=1; i<=num_nodes; i++)
    {
        nodes[i]=G.nodes[i];
    }
}

void Graph::add_edge(int start, int end)
{
    nodes[start].push(end);
    if(start!=end)
    {
        nodes[end].push(start);
    }
}

Graph::Node& Graph::operator[](int i)
{
    return nodes[i];
}

void Graph::print()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=num_nodes; i++)
    {
        nodes[i].print();
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

Graph::~Graph()
{
    delete[] nodes;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream f("graph.txt");

    Graph G(f);

    G.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be correct with that guess :)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Oh, understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add spaces to improve readability:

```
head = NULL;
while (tmp)
if (this != &F)
```

Member functions that do not change any of the class members should be declared with the `const` specifier:

```
bool is_empty() const;
bool is_leaf() const;
```

Some of your `while` loops could be rewritten as `for` loops.  For example, the loop in the `Node` copy constructor could be rewritten as

```
for (adj* tmp = F.head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    push(tmp->data);
```

Should a `pop` with an empty list be tolerated?  Currently you silently ignore the problem by returning a -1.  Would throwing an exception (to report the error) be better?  Or at least a `std::assert(false);` before the return, so you can detect the problem in a debug build.  Also, you don't need the `else` there, since the body of the `if` will return.

You have no error checking.  In particular, `add_edge` will happily try to add an edge to a node that doesn't exist, resulting in Undefined Behavior and (if you're lucky) a crash.  (The same applies to `Graph::operator[]`.  You could add an assert check, or an `at` method that would check the bounds, similar to how `std::vector` operates.)

Your `Graph` copy constructor does not copy `nodes[0]`.

Why are you using raw memory for Graph's `nodes`?  You should use `std::vector` or some form of smart pointer.

Comment: I'm very thankful for your comment. Now I have added spaces, rewritten the while loops. I initially used exception handling but then removed it. Now I re-added it. There is still something I really don't understand. First, I start my indexes by 1, so that's why I'm not copying `nodes[0]`, since it doesn't store any valuable data, just an empty list. The other thing, I thought the `~Node` destructor frees up the allocated memory.  Also, why should I delete the `this` object if I want to copy it? 

PS: I haven't learnt to use the STLs so that's why I didn't included them in my code.

Comment: @BalogSzilárd I completely missed `~Node` since it isn't near the constructors.  It would probably make sense to locate the destructor next to the constructors, since what they do is related.  The assignment operator sets `head` to NULL, and doesn't free up any of the `adj` objects that are currently stored in `this`.

Comment: OMG now I completely understand . Should I explicitly call the destructor as `this->~Node()` or just simply type the right code to do it? I'm completely grateful for your time and for your help. I thought it would be a good idea to write the destructors at the end of that list since it is the last thing a function executes, but it seems its not the case. Anyways, big thanks! Have a great day!

Comment: @BalogSzilárd Don't call the destructor.  Since duplicating code is not a good idea, you can put what the destructor does into a (private) function (`cleanup` or something like that), then call that from the destructor and the copy assignment operator.  Then maybe just do the memory handling that `pop` does, without having to track or return a value (or have multiple redundant checks for empty).